# Unable to get $_GET values from form

Tags: php, html, forms, input, get

I cannot retrieve the `$_GET['id']` nor `$_GET['action']` from a form and input in this page:

```
<?php
include "common.php";
var_dump($_GET['quantity']);
var_dump($_GET['action']);
var_dump($_GET['id']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>es6.1.6</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=sizeof($names); $i++) {
        echo "<form method='get' action='shop.php?action=add&id=$i'>";
        echo "<li><a href='description.php?item=$i'> ",$names[$i],"</a></li>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='quantity'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>

<br><br>
<form action="summary.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

only `$_GET['quantity']` will be set after inserting a number and pressing Enter into any input form

Comment: @NigelRen the problem is that action=add is not set as well as the id=$i
I've edited the post

Comment: the two forms have different `action`... the first `shop.php?action=add&id=$i` while the second `summary.php` it's impossible to have both working as expected because the first loads `shop.php` while the second loads `summary.php`

Comment: I think will be executed only the second form with `action="summary.php"` because it's the only that has a `<input type="submit"...` the first will not be executed since hasn't a `submit` input type... so you'll never get the `action` and the `id` values...

Comment: If you want get values from the two different forms you can serve the same php file in the `action`... first form: `<form method='get' action='shop.php?action=add&id=$i'>` and the second form: `<form method='get' action='shop.php?summary=true'>`... I suggest to use `POST` method instead `GET` since you are managing sensible data...

Comment: @Alessandro I need to load two different pages, description.php when clicking on any of the item in the list and loading the same shop.php page with new values. Is that possible?

Comment: It's not possible, when you get the first form you'll load `shop.php` and so you'll leave your current form... and cannot load at the same time `description.php` or `summary.php`, any `action form` will leave the `current form` and so you'll be into another `php page`, my suggestion is use the `current page` (example: shop.php) with `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?action=add&amp;id=$i"...`

Comment: I didn't meant to load two php pages at the same time, but I need two different form in that list to load different pages, because when I click on any of the item in the list I need to load a different page with a description, but when I set any of the input number and press Enter I need to load the summary page

Comment: When you click on a `item` in the `list` you don't `"load"` the wished page, but you are `leaving` the `current page` and `moving` into another page, `action` means _"leave the current page and go to the action url"_ [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Answer (score 1):

try adding action and id as hidden input fields with the values you need

edit:
change your code to look like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=sizeof($names); $i++) {
        echo "<form method='get' action='shop.php'>";
        echo "<li><a href='description.php?item=$i'> ",$names[$i],"</a></li>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='quantity'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='add'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $i . "'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

Comment: Without `<input type="sumbit"...` the user have to press Enter to get the form working...